# not quite understand 'a option

Tags: ocaml, option-type

```
class window = 
  object
    val mutable top_widget = (None : widget option)
    method top_widget = top_widget
  end
and widget (w : window) = 
  object
    val window = w
    method window = window
  end;;
```

There are two things I do not understand:

1. `(None : widget option)` what does this mean? Also, in general how do we use `'a option`?
2. `(w : window)` this means `w` is a parameter of class `widget`, which is of type window?

Answer (score 3):

A value of type `'a option` has two forms:

```
None
Some x
```

Where `x` is a value of type `'a`.

For example here are two values of type `int option`:

```
None
Some 421
```

This is probably obvious, but the idea is that the type represents a value that might or might not be present. The value `None` represents an absent value.

Yes, the notation `(w: window)` means that the class `widget` has a parameter that's a window. When you create a widget it would look like this:

```
let mywidget = new widget mywindow in
. . .
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. Now I understand 'a option and parametrized class. But what does this mean: (None : widget option)? it is a option but with type widget? kinda confused.

Comment: `None` is polymorphic, i.e., it can represent a value of any type `'a option`. This code is specifying the type of this particular `None`, mostly for documentation.